# How is the battery on my riding mower charged?

Tags: battery, alternator, lawnmower

I just started my riding mower for the season and in doing the basics (oil change, spark plug, air filter cleaning, take the trickle charger leads off) I was looking at the mower and realized I didn't see anything like an alternator -- I know it has to have one, or else I'd have to trickle charge it between uses. How is the battery on my mower recharged? It's a craftsman LT2000, but I assume all riding mowers built just about the same.

Comment: You've answered your own question: it has an alternator.

Answer (score 1):

The "alternator" is built into the flywheel - manufacturers tend to minimize components on smaller machines and separate alternators are used but tend to be on engines above a certain size as that also means fan belts etc which if required to drive other components becomes viable.

Comment: So does essentially use the starter to generate voltage?